# Image link of firebase storage is returning null - Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flutter-web

While showing the image's fiorebase storage link, I'm getting this error
network_image_web.dart:26:16
url != null  is not true

Below is the sample. And yes provider is getting all the other fields fine except the pic

```
class AddAlreadyExistingProductsView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddAlreadyExistingProductsViewState createState() =>
      _AddAlreadyExistingProductsViewState();
}

class _AddAlreadyExistingProductsViewState
    extends State<AddAlreadyExistingProductsView> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final _productsList = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context);

return Scaffold(
............
    child: 
       SearchableDropdown.single(
       ............
            items: _productsList.map((value) {
               print("---> pic : " + value.pic.toString()); // <--- NULL HERE
          ..........        
       child: ListTile(
             leading: CircleAvatar(
               backgroundImage: NetworkImage(value.pic),
            ),
           subtitle: Text(value.name)
.............
                                ) 
                             )
                            }
```

```
class MainDataProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       StreamProvider<List<Product>>.value(
        value: DatabaseService().getAllProducts,
........
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: AddAlreadyExistingProductsView (),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried to print it, while printing the image and retured null. Retrieval of all the other feilds is fine. I gave the static value of that image stored inside the firebase database inside the Network image and it worked fine. But while getting data dynamically it is not working. I don't know why. I got the data in same way in mobile and it worked but for flutter web it is not working.

Here is Product model code

```
  Stream<List<Product>> get getAllProducts {
    return productCollection.get().asStream().map(_productDataFromSnapshot);
  }

  List<Product> _productDataFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    List<Product> productsList = List<Product>();

    for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.docs.length; i++) {
      productsList.add(Product(
        productID: snapshot.docs[i].data()['productID'] ?? "",
        name: snapshot.docs[i].data()['name'] ?? "",
        volume: snapshot.docs[i].data()['volume'] ?? "",
        price: snapshot.docs[i].data()['price'] ?? "",
        quantity: snapshot.docs[i].data()['quantity'] ?? "",
        brand: snapshot.docs[i].data()['brand'] ?? "",
        productAttribute: snapshot.docs[i].data()['productAttribute'] ?? "",
        productCtgName: snapshot.docs[i].data()['productCtgName'] ?? "",
        productSubCtgName: snapshot.docs[i].data()['productSubCtgName'] ?? "",
        productCtgID: snapshot.docs[i].data()['productCtgID'] ?? "",
        productSubCtgID: snapshot.docs[i].data()['productSubCtgID'] ?? "",
      ));
    }
    return productsList;
  }


class Product {
  String productID;
  String name;
  int price;
  int salePrice;
  DateTime addDate;
  String volume;
  int quantity;
  String productAttribute;
  String productSubCtgID;
  String productCtgID;
  String productSubCtgName;
  String productCtgName;
  String brand;
  String pic;

  Product({
    this.productID,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.addDate,
    this.volume,
    this.quantity,
    this.productAttribute,
    this.brand,
    this.productCtgID,
    this.productSubCtgID,
    this.productCtgName,
    this.productSubCtgName,
    this.pic,
    this.salePrice,
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Share your Product model.

Comment: @Siddharthjha Sorry my bad. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the _productDataFromSnapshot function in the for loop , you are not initialising the pic field.

To prevent these types of mistakes use @required for such type of fields